# Facebook graph api's invite friend accept callback (iOS)

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, callback, facebook-invite

I couldn't find any answer to my question:

On my facebook iOS app, if the user invites his friends (via the `method: apprequests` thing), is it possible for me to know whether/how many friends answered "OK" to this invitation ?